# Plugins Tab Disappeared For No Reason?

Tags: notepad++

So I was using Notepad++ as per completely normal, went to use the compare plugin, and it's no longer there. I've literally changed nothing about my installation, and the plugins tab has always been there before now, but it's just randomly disappeared. How do I get it back?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You must have at least one plugin with **.dll** extension in *Plugins* directory inside Notepad++ directory.

Details:

Notepad++ shows submenu **Plugins** if you have at least one file compatible with file mask `*.dll*` in Plugins directory inside Notepad++ directory.

So if your **notepad++.exe** is in the following location

```
C:\Tools\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
```

then you must have for example this file present

```
C:\Tools\Notepad++\Plugins\SomePlugin.dll@#
```

and then the **Plugins** submenu is displayed. Put some plugins there and your problem is solved.

Notes:

- You surely noted that I gave example of `SomePlugin.dll@#` instead of just proper `SomePlugin.dll` but actually this is how Notepad++ currently works. For locating plugin libraries in **Plugins** directory, it uses `*.dll*`, not `*.dll`.
- You can use any valid plugin to get it working, plugin called **Plugin Manager** is not required.

So check what happened to your **Plugins** directory and eventually get the files again by

- re-installing Notepad++ (just install over the same version) and basic plugins will appear
- getting plugin **Plugin Manager** and using it to download and install other plugins
- restoring the Plugins directory from your backup (**Recommended.** This way you can restore configuration files of your plugins, too. Just restore the subdirectories in **Plugins** directory.)
- manually copying the plugins from downloaded files or from another Notepad++ instance

All this applies for Notepad++ versions up to 7.5.9. Version 7.6 update log states:

> 2. Change plugin loading method: Remove the legacy plugin loading way and apply only the new plugin loading method.

so some details may differ in the most recent versions. But plugins you need must be present anyway, check for them.

Comment: Thank you, reinstalling worked. I do not know why the bug occurred as I made no changes to my installation prior, and there were plugins in the plugins directory. Perhaps it was due to the new update.

Comment: @PeterSutherns – thank you for letting me know. I recommend to mark the most helpful answer as accepted (and optionally use the voting buttons) – see [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should reinstall the plugin manager.

Here are some references:

- [FAQ Desk: The missing plugin manager](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/15745/faq-desk-the-missing-plugin-manager)
  discusses matching the plugin manager version to that of Notepad++
- [nppPluginManager
  download](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases)
- [plugin manager installation notes](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/blob/master/doc/index.html#install)

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> import -> import plugin

search for your "plugin.dll" and restart npp